# How to send and receive headers via PHP

Tags: php, http, header, http-headers

I'd like to study how headers are sent and received.

I know about PHP's `header` function and think I can just look at an actual request header (e.g. using Firebug) and make identical requests to a server (including spoofing the User-Agent). Is this correct?

The other problem is how do I get the header responses back? I want to analyze the response.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

@Tatu, here's the code I ran:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/540.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.10 Chrome/8.1.0.0 Safari/540.0');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo($result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [cURL](http://www.php.net/curl) which will allow you to make requests and set and inspect headers. PHP's `header` only sets headers for the current page, you cannot use that to spoof your user agent – these are headers set by the server and as such have no such significance.

The basic structure of a cURL request with custom headers might be something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Your user agent");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The beginning of `$result` will now contain the headers received from the server.

Comment: Just for clarification, I can "spoof" User-Agent using cURL, right? I just want to see how servers respond to different user agents.

Comment: I tried your code, but I didn't get headers (I got the actual file response, though). I'm editing my original post so I can show you my code.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, you need to have `CURLOPT_HEADER` set to 1 which I accidentally had as 0 in my example.

Comment: I only want the headers. Is there a way to get just that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send headers yourself, without using cURL, check out sockets in PHP.

http://php.net/sockets

Comment: After you graduate from cURL - then sockets give you amazing power. But you can still do almost anything with cURL.

Comment: yep, cURL provides better interface, but nothing beats raw sockets :-)